# Facebook ads Suspended,what can i do?

Tags: facebook, ads

I created a facebook ad with my personal account(what i use since six years),but it's been suspended.I sent my photo id over two week but there's still no reply.
I try to create ads with my friends' facebooks and computers,credit cards and of course different ads but thoose get suspended too?
What am i doing wrong?
Why facebook suspend a totally cleared ad?I paid 1500usd to a webside it looks professional i used the same computer and still they suspended it.
Can i make a complaint against facebook or its just a waste of time?
Is there any timeframe facebook has to reply me?

Thanks for help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is regarding Facebook customer support.

Comment: Hi there Peter, unfortunately, you seem to have landed on the wrong site. [so] deals with technical questions related to programming while your post is talking about the usage of Facebook's platform and their customer support.

Answer (score 0):

We should close this question as others suggested but to give you a pointer, you should fill this form out and create ticket.

https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=531795380173090